# Android - In multiple alert dialogs need to dismiss only current focused dialog

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, android-notifications, android-dialog

I have multiple alert dialogs in an activity. When all the dialogs arise at same time, on key listener back press all the dialogs are dismissed. I need to dismiss only the current focused dialog. Is it possible ?

```
 public class NotificationAlert extends Activity {

private Locale myLocale;
private SharedPreferences settings;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    settings = this.getSharedPreferences(
            getString(R.string.preferences_name), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    myLocale = new Locale(settings.getString("langCode", "EN")
            .toLowerCase());
    final Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    String message = bundle.getString(NotificationFactory.MESSAGE);
    int myId = bundle.getInt(NotificationFactory.MY_ID, -1);
    final int alarmId = bundle
            .getInt(NotificationFactory.ALARM_ID, -1);// Request
    int alarmType = bundle.getInt(NotificationFactory.ALRAM_TYPE,
            NotificationFactory.ALRAM_TYPE_UNKOWN);// Alarm type

    if (alarmType == NotificationFactory.ALRAM_TYPE_DAILY) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
        View dialoglayout = inflater.inflate(
                R.layout.my_profile, null);
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                NotificationAlert.this);
        builder.setView(dialoglayout);
        LinearLayout dismiss = (LinearLayout) dialoglayout
                .findViewById(R.id.ok_error_alert);
        TextView content = (TextView) dialoglayout
                .findViewById(R.id.errorContent);
        TextView okAlert = (TextView) dialoglayout
                .findViewById(R.id.okAlert);
        okAlert.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.dismiss));
        content.setText(String.valueOf(message));
        final AlertDialog  alertDialog = builder.create();
        dismiss.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                finish();
                alertDialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        builder.setOnCancelListener(new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
                // if from activity
                NotificationAlert.this.finish();
            }

        });
        alertDialog.setOnKeyListener(new Dialog.OnKeyListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onKey(DialogInterface arg0, int keyCode,
                    KeyEvent event) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
                    finish();
                    alertDialog.dismiss();
                }
                return true;
            }
        });
        alertDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
        alertDialog.show();
    } else if (alarmType == NotificationFactory.ALRAM_TYPE_MONTHLY) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
        View dialoglayout = inflater.inflate(
                R.layout.monthly_popup, null);
        TextView content = (TextView) dialoglayout
                .findViewById(R.id.text_message);
        content.setText(String.valueOf(message));
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                NotificationAlert.this);
        builder.setView(dialoglayout);
        TextView tick = (TextView) dialoglayout
                .findViewById(R.id.button1);
        TextView dismiss = (TextView) dialoglayout
                .findViewById(R.id.button2);
        final AlertDialog  alertDialog = builder.create();
        alertDialog.setOnKeyListener(new Dialog.OnKeyListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onKey(DialogInterface arg0, int keyCode,
                    KeyEvent event) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
                    finish();
                    alertDialog.dismiss();
                }
                return true;
            }
        });
        tick.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Calling symptom tracker fragment
                alertDialog.dismiss();
                finish();
             }
        });
        dismiss.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                finish();
                alertDialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        builder.setOnCancelListener(new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
                NotificationAlert.this.finish();
            }

        });
        alertDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
        alertDialog.show();
    } else if (alarmType == AlarmNotificationFactory.ALRAM_TYPE_YEARLY) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
        View dialoglayout = inflater.inflate(
                R.layout.yearly_popup, null);
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                NotificationAlert.this);
        builder.setView(dialoglayout);
        LinearLayout dismiss = (LinearLayout) dialoglayout
                .findViewById(R.id.ok_error_alert);
        TextView content = (TextView) dialoglayout
                .findViewById(R.id.errorContent);
        TextView okAlert = (TextView) dialoglayout
                .findViewById(R.id.okAlert);
        okAlert.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.dismiss));
        content.setText(String.valueOf(message));
        final AlertDialog  alertDialog = builder.create();
        alertDialog.setOnKeyListener(new Dialog.OnKeyListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onKey(DialogInterface arg0, int keyCode,
                    KeyEvent event) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
                    finish();
                    alertDialog.dismiss();
                }
                return true;
            }
        });
        dismiss.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                finish();
                alertDialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        builder.setOnCancelListener(new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
                NotificationAlert.this.finish();
            }

        });
        alertDialog.show();

    } 
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
}

}
```

Comment: Its because you have called alertDialog.setOnKeyListener(new Dialog.OnKeyListener()  for every dialog

Comment: then what can i use to get the current focused dialog dismissed on back press ?

Comment: I dont know exact answer but try  alertDialog.setOnKeyListener  for all dialog and make flag which dialog is in front and finish dialog according to that flag and also rename dialog

Comment: Can you elaborate your idea pls ?

Comment: have you set multiple onclick listeners for button

Comment: No. i have set onclick listeners only for those respective buttons in the dialogs mentioned in the above code

Comment: I am talking in general

Comment: I think you are doing mistake here . 
You are finishing activity inside on CancelListener 

NotificationAlert.this.finish();

Don't do this.